# how to change the whole dataframe values based on another one in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,5,4,2], 'B':[1,2,4,1,2,3], 'C':[2,3,1,4,2,3]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'num':[1,2,3,4,5],'col':['red','red','blue','orange','orange']})
```

They look like this:

```
df:
        A   B   C
    0   1   1   2
    1   2   2   3
    2   3   4   1
    3   5   1   4
    4   4   2   2
    5   2   3   3

df1:

       col    num
   0    red     1
   1    red     2
   2    blue    3
   3    orange  4
   4    orange  5
```

what i want is the dataframe df with values of df1:

```
df_new:
        A       B     C
    0   red     red     red
    1   red     red     blue
    2   blue    orange  red
    3   orange  red     orange
    4   orange  red     red
    5   red     blue    blue
```

Bearing in mind that I have lots of rows in df, and have thousands of different values as well.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set the index to the `num` col on `df1` then you can call `apply` with a `lambda` and use `map` to perform the lookup on each column:

```
In [11]:
df2 = df1.set_index('num')
df.apply(lambda x: x.map(df2['col']))

Out[11]:
        A       B       C
0     red     red     red
1     red     red    blue
2    blue  orange     red
3  orange     red  orange
4  orange     red     red
5     red    blue    blue
```

Comment: Thanks so much for quick response, i have been thinking of this for a while! Bless you!

Comment: yes, had to wait for a couple of minutes to be able to accept the answer. It's fast enough for me.